# How to integrate PHPed with Git

Tags: git, phped

I am developing using PHPEd. Our company is just moving to Git. Regarding Nusphere support, there is no native support for Git in PHPEd - shell script should be used. As I have no experience with it, please, could anybody of you help me with the scripting and setup - any hints? Does anybody of you real experience with this?

Comment: PhpED is just a PHP IDE, correct? You should be able to use any git client with it, with no need for additional scripting. If you're not using the git CLI (which I highly recommend, by the way), you should be able to use any git GUI client, such as SourceTree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I have found no automatic way, so currently I use SmartGit as external tool ...

Answer (score 2):

TortoiseGIT is a right way for doing this. After installing and configuring Tortoise, you'll be able to run git commands directly from Windows Explorer as well as from PHPEd's own windows. See Shell in popup menus.

Comment: I actually don't recommend TortoiseGit, since it's heavily influenced by TortoiseSVN, and thus, SVN-style workflows, instead of git-style workflows. Users should be able to use any git client, not just TortoiseGit.

Answer (score 2):

I switched from Eclipse PDT Kepler to phpED.
As replacemnet of Eclipse git plugin Egit, I started to use SourceTree. I find it powerfull with a nice interface, but a bit slow.

EDIT : a bit slow with repositories hosted on network shares but fast on local repositories

Comment: With time I totally stopped to use SourceTree. Using git command line with appropriate color highlight is totally sufficient.
Useful alias to see commits tree :
    alias gitlog='git log --graph --full-history --all --no-prefix --color --pretty=format:"%x1b[31m%h%x09%x1b[32m%d%x1b[0m%x20%x1b[0m%x20%s%x1b[36m%x20%an%x1b[0m%$